# What do I use to mesure if there's any significance between two sets of rating results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Suppose, I wanted to test if condition 'A' and 'B' have any effect in the quality of writing a sentence. I have 25 participants write a short sentence for each condition (therefore, I have 25 sentence written under condition 'A' and another 25 under condition 'B').

Then I recruit three experts to rate those 50 sentences (in randomized order) regarding four criteria: "interesting", "genuine", "personal story involved", "sounds like preaching"? The experts answer "yes/no" to all these criteria for all 50 sentences and based on the majority voting, I consider assign tags to these sentences (e.g., If 2 out of 3 experts say a sentence is "interesting", I label that sentence as "interesting").

Below is what I got for the number of sentences labeled as tags in the column.

```
             "Interesting"       "Genuine"         "Personal"      "Preaching"
Condition A:     24                  16               20              12

Condition B:     23                  22               16              15
```

(Note: the total of these two rows are not 50 because some sentences are rated by majority of experts as "not interesting", "not genuine", "not personal", "not preaching" etc.

**My question is: It seems like in "Genuine" case, there is enough of a gap between condition 'A' and 'B'. But I don't know what statistical technique to use to claim that the gap is SIGNIFICANT**

If anyone has idea/direction/suggestion as to that, I would greatly appreciate that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I assume that "Genuine" was the only criterion you looked at, I would have observed the following frequency table:

```
          Genuine   Not Genuine  Total
Group 1     16     34         50
Group 2     22     28         50
Total       38     62         100
```

The chi-square value for this table (/testing for independence) is $\chi^2(1)=1.06, p=0.303$ with Yates-correction.

Some points worth considering:

- If you are interested in the size of differences ("enough of a gap" for what exactly?), significance testing is not producing the answer you might be interested in.
- consider improving the measurement model: a binary evaluation is very crude and finding interrater-disagreement makes the measure appear even more problematic. Most manipulations are unlikely to produce strong efects when using measures like these. (using continuous scales would be of questionable help from a scientific point of view: finding a miniscule, but significant, difference of a quarter scale point near the mid-scale value is not really exciting).
- consider having precise hypotheses for all your meaasures before data collection, do not engage in cherry-picking afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you sample statistics is not so large (N=25 events per condition) and you often observe values $n_A$ or $n_B$ close to 25, so I'm not sure approximating the distribution of $n$ by normal law is appropriate. I would rather use binomial laws like:

$p(N=n) = C_{N}^{n} p^{n} (1 - p)^{N-n}$

with $p$ the probability that condition "i" is genuine for a given sentence and $n$ the number of sentences declared as "genuine" out of $N$.

Second you need to define your null H0 and alternative H1 hypothesis:

- H0: "condA and condB gives similar result in the genuine case"
- H1: "condB gives better results than condition A"

Third, you need a model on which you perform a test, you start from the joint distribution of $n_A$ and $n_B$ expressed generally as:

$L(n_A, n_B | p_A, p_B, N) = C_N^{n_A} p_A^{n_A} (1 - p_A)^{N-n_A} C_N^{n_B} p_B^{n_B} (1 - p_B)^{N-n_B}$

to relate it to your hypothesis test, you can rewrite it with the following change of variables $p_A = p$, $p_B = p + \mu$

$L(n_A, n_B | \mu, p, N) = C_N^{n_A} p^{n_A} (1 - p)^{N-n_A} C_N^{n_B} (p+\mu)^{n_B} (1 - p - \mu)^{N-n_B}$

the two hypothesis write as:

- H0: $\mu = 0$
- H1: $\mu > 0$

$\mu$ is the parameter of interest in your problem whereas $p$ is an (annoying) nuisance parameter.

Finally, you need to perform a test like the likelihood ratio test which is quite common because nuisance parameters are treated by profiling:

$\Lambda = L(n_A, n_B | \mu=0, \hat{\hat{p}}, N) / L(n_A, n_B | \hat{\mu}, \hat{p}, N)$

with $\hat{\hat{p}}$ and $\hat{\mu}, \hat{p}$ the conditional and unconditional maximum likelihood estimates respectively.

I guess problem can be solved analytically, but I'm lazy, so I computed with some quick python macro and got a pvalue of 0.043 (assuming Wilks approximation holds which seems to be the case) which is smaller than the standard choice of 0.05. You can say that you refuted H0 (condition A and B give similar results) at 95% CL (if I did no mistake).

Note that if I would have omitted the impact of the nuisance parameter, I would have got a much lower $pvalue = Prob(n >= 22 | p=16/25, N=25) \simeq 0.007$. It is therefore important in this problem to include the fact we do not know $p$.